# Index Times takes so long in magento 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2.3.2, index

Hello I would like to ask a few things about Indexing.
I am using Magento 2.3.2 and i am building a website in localhost. Until now i have imported 45.000 products.
I runned index and it took about 9 hours for 45.000 products! please see bellow times.

```
    info@LAPTOP-5SEJ1RGM c:\xampp\htdocs\gigaparts'

    php bin/magento indexer:reindex

    Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 05:12:13  
    Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:29  
    Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:11  
    Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00  
    Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:03:55  
    Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 03:25:39
```

What if i reach 500.000 or 700.000 references? how long it will need?
Also lets say i am at 700.000 and i add one more reference. (I will import new references through ERP system linked to magento).
How long will it need to appear to my site?
Are these times normal? Or there is a bug?
Should i try different magento version? 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Category Products index, Catalog Search** is taking a too long time because of two reasons:

- **Category Products may be taking much time, because of this you might
  assign your products to wrong categories.**

Like

> Assign all  products to all categories
>
> Suppose, categories at 3rd levels like **Man>Clothing>Jean**. You have
>   Assing Jeans category's products to **Clothing**  & **Man** from
>   **Products in Category**. Those do not need. If you make Enable **Achor** of those categories then automatically assign to **Clothing**  & **Man**  and it will show at frontend.
>
> You have to manage the category and product assignment right way.

- **Check All 3rd party extensions, if any module has wrong logic/code is responsible for this issue.**
- **Don't use Window system, Use Linux system, Window is not good as
  magento 2 server**.
- **Magento 2.3 Open source use elasticsearch as Search instead of MySQL
  search for Magento search** .See details at
  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html.

Comment: So in my case i have  default category  -genuine spare parts  -scania.  All products i added in both genuine spare parts and scania category. i should only assign them in scania?